# Python - Create a Bar Chart of Average Estimated Salary by c_rating, but do a facet_wrap by gender

Tags: python

My data set is Churn_Modeling:

```
RowNumber     CustomerId     Surname    CreditScore     Geography   Gender  Age Tenure    Balance   NumOfProducts   HasCrCard   IsActiveMember  EstimatedSalary Exited
        1       15634602    Hargrave            619       France    Female  42       2          0               1           1                1        101348.88     1
        2       15647311        Hill            608       Spain     Female  41       1   83807.86               1           0                1        112542.58     0
        3       15619304        Onio            502       France    Female  42       8   159660.8               3           1                0        113931.57     1
        4       15701354        Boni            699       France    Female  39       1          0               2           0                0         93826.63     0
        5       15737888    Mitchell            850       Spain     Female  43       2  125510.82               1           1                1          79084.1     0
        6       15574012         Chu            645       Spain     Male    44       8  113755.78               2           1                0        149756.71     1
```

I created a column called c_rating with the following ranges: (<500 -="very poor",  500-600="poor",  601-660="fair", 661-780="good",  and >= 780 – "excellent") with code:

```
from plotnine import *
from dfply import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import datetime as dt
```

```
a_churn = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modeling.csv")

a_churn['c_rating'] = pd.cut(a_churn['CreditScore'], bins=[0,500,600,660,780,1000],labels = ['very poor', 'poor', 'fair', 'good', 'excellent'])

a_churn
```

I am trying to create a Bar Chart of Average Estimated Salary by c_rating, but do a facet_wrap by gender.

```
(a_churn >>
  group_by(X.c_rating) >>
  summarise(avg_est_salary = X.EstimatedSalary.mean()) >>
  ggplot(mapping=aes(x=avg_est_salary,y = 'c_rating')) +geom_bar(stat = "identity"))
```

However I get the error c_rating is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_bar, facet_wrap
import pandas as pd

a_churn = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modeling.csv')
a_churn['c_rating'] = pd.cut(a_churn['CreditScore'], bins=[0,500,600,660,780,1000],labels = ['very poor', 'poor', 'fair', 'good', 'excellent'])

p = ggplot(a_churn) + aes(x='c_rating', y='EstimatedSalary') + geom_bar(stat='identity', alpha=0.8) + facet_wrap('Gender')
print(p)
```

[image: Bar plot - Churn Modelling]